# The data type of the new values don’t match with that of the column factor while doing update

Tags: dolphindb

I had a factor table. Now, I want to add a number to each factors of certain rows. The demo codes are shown as below:

```
factor=table(now() as tradeTime,`600009 as secID,1.0 as factor1,2.0 as factor2,3.0 as             
factor3,4.0 as factore4,5.0 as factor5)
for(i in factor.columnNames()){
    if(left(i,6)!="factor") 
        continue
    update!(factor, i, i + 10)
}
```

But when I run these scripts in DolphinDB GUI, I get an error: “The data type of the new values does not match the data type of column factor1”. The error still remains even though I change the number 10 to 10.0. What’s the problem?

Answer (score 1):

update! (factor, i, i + 10) where i is a string, i+10 is a string, not a field, so it can be changed to:

```py
update!(factor, i, factor[i] + 10)
```

or

```py
factor[i] = factor[i] + 10
```

or

```py
update!(factor, i, expr(sqlCol(i), +, 10))
```